# How do you join one column based on multiple columns WITHOUT having to rename columns?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to run a SQL query to join one column on the condition of multiple columns. So if there's an ID match in table 2 that matches with ID1 and ID2 in table 1, the value in table 1 gets joined to table 2. If there's a NULL in ID2 but not in ID1 in table 1 and exists in table 2, that should also still be able to join.

Is there a way to do this without having to rename columns?

[image: Join requirement]

Comment: Can you please elaborate your JOIN condition a bit further ? What should ID in table2 match with in table1 ?

Comment: Can you also provide an example of the query that you have tried so far ? Especially can you clarify why do you want " to do this without having to rename columns? "

Comment: "So if there's an ID match in table 2 that matches with ID1 and ID2 in table 1". Does that mean that ID has to match both ID1 and ID2?

Answer (score 0):

You may join your tables as the following:

```
SELECT T.ID1, T.ID2, T.ID3, D.Trips
FROM Table1 T JOIN Table2 D
ON D.ID IN (T.ID1, T.ID2, T.ID3)
ORDER BY COALESCE(T.ID1, T.ID2, T.ID3)
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/pL2Fp9-8).